# Policy issue: Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

What should i do to solve this problem i use this permissions

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Hello Google Play Developer,

Our records show that your app, appname , with package name app.appname, currently violates our User Data policy regarding Personal and Sensitive Information.

Policy issue: Google Play requires developers to provide a valid privacy policy when the app requests or handles sensitive user or device information. Your app requests sensitive permissions (e.g. camera, microphone, accounts, contacts, or phone) or user data, but does not include a valid privacy policy.

Action required: Include a link to a valid privacy policy on your app's Store Listing page and within your app. You can find more information in our help center.

Alternatively, you may opt-out of this requirement by removing any requests for sensitive permissions or user data.

If you have additional apps in your catalog, please make sure they are compliant with our Prominent Disclosure requirements.

Please resolve this issue by January 30, 2017, or administrative action will be taken to limit the visibility of your app, up to and including removal from the Play Store. Thanks for helping us provide a clear and transparent experience for Google Play users.

Regards,

The Google Play Team

Comment: "What should i do to solve this problem" -- "Action required: Include a link to a valid privacy policy on your app's Store Listing page and within your app. You can find more information in our help center.  Alternatively, you may opt-out of this requirement by removing any requests for sensitive permissions or user data."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a code error.

While updating an app to Google Play, you need to provide a Privacy Policy for your application. That is always not mandatory but since your app is using personal information of a user, you have to provide a privacy policy.

Just search for some examples of policies and create your own. 
It is just a word document containing information. 
You will also get sites online that develop a privacy policy document for you.

One your document is ready, just upload it on your Google Drive with only 'view' permission and then paste the link of that document in your app's console.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Do I also need to add a link in my app? Or adding link to store listing is enough?

Comment: @PamirCevikogullari adding link to the store listing is enough. But if you want your user to accept the policy then you can add it to your app as well.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is not related to pragramming i will just say that google is asking you to provide privacy policy of your app.

It means that you need to give **clerification about all those permissions** and why do you need those in your application.

Just because you are using some sensitive permission which required user's attention, you need to specify why you need those permissions.

They have already given you evertything that what you need to do and what not.

> Include a link to a valid privacy policy on your app's Store Listing
>   page and within your app. You can find more information in our help
>   center.

Comment: can you tell me what should i do ? you mean that i need add link in my app about it ?! or what you mean

Comment: can you please read this line again? `Include a link to a valid privacy policy on your app's Store Listing page and within your app.`

Comment: oh i got i will add link on play store to explain it really thanks so much man <3 it asked me for it but i ignore it now i will go to add link to it